# Complex analysis: Iso-lineal shear mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

EDIT1:

A complex number has magnitude and direction. In conformal mappings 2D complex plane functions preserve angles in conformal mappings but curvilinear rectangle side lengths change, undergo a dilation .. basically as dilatory maps.

What complex mapping leaves lengths unchanged but varies the angles by a shear action? Whether examples like Chebychev nets in 3D can be brought into 2D also?

Comment: Not an holomorphic one

Comment: If such a map exists (which I doubt), it's going to be horrible: since one can define the angle between two curves in terms of the limits of lengths of curves (or in terms of infinitesimal lengths), for angles not to be preserved the map would have to be differentiable nowhere.

Comment: 3D Chebychev nets for constant positive and negative Gauss curvature e.g., on surfaces of revolution are known. I am curious about 2D.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro  Shall change, if only for a start.